# Showing truncated div within scrollable div

Tags: html, css

In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps3331333/z9v3nvee/2/) I have a div that contains some text and another div. The container is scrollable.

The internal div is truncated, and I need to display it completely at any time (i.e. shouldn't be truncated or hidden). I cannot use position:absolute in the internal div. Is this achievable?

```
<div style="background-color:orange;height:100px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <p>
       some text in the div
    </p>
    <p>
       more text in the div
   </p>
   <div style="z-index:29999;background-color:yellow;width:80px">
        I need to show this text, shouldn't be truncated
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display it completely at any time"? Can you eliminate the `height: 100px;` on the outer div?

Comment: it means that it should be displayed, not truncated. I cannot eliminate the height

Comment: So if it must not be truncated, you must either increase the height, set it to auto (eliminate it), or set the width to a larger value as pointed out in answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="background-color:orange;height:100px;overflow:auto">
<p>
some text in the div
</p>
<p>
more text in the div
</p>
<div style="z-index:29999;background-color:yellow;"> -->remove width from here`enter code here`
  I need to show this text, shouldn't be truncated
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: set "overflow:auto" in Main div. and Remove width from inner Div

Answer (score 0):

remove the `width:80px` from the child `<div>`and put in `max-width:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="background-color:orange;height:100px;overflow-y:scroll">
<p>
some text in the div
</p>
<p>
more text in the div
</p>
<div style="z-index:29999;background-color:yellow;max-width:100%;">
  I need to show this text, shouldn't be truncated
</div>
</div>
```